# Use SQL To Filter Table Where I Need to Sum Multiple Rows Of A Column Based On Another Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, having-clause

I'm trying to filter a table, where there are multiple rows for a single member for each store they have purchased items at. Plus columns for number of meat and vegetable items purchased. I want to have a list of people and all the stores where they have purchases meat *and* vegetables.

Source table:

`MemberId  |  StoreId  | Meat  |  Vegegetables
   1           11          1         2
   1           12          0         1
   1           14          1         2
   2           12          1         0
   3           12          1         0
   3           12          1         0
   4           11          2         1
   4           13          0         1
   4           14          0         1`

The filter I want to apply is:

For a MemberId (across all stores): WHERE SUM(Meat) > 0 AND SUM(Vegetables) > 0

So I'm looking for this results table

`MemberId  |  StoreId  | Meat  |  Vegetables
   1           11          1         2
   1           12          0         1
   1           14          1         2
   4           11          2         1
   4           13          0         1
   4           14          0         1`

This has got me stumped and I can't work out how to filter this table.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using `sum` window function.

```
select * from (
select t.*,sum(meat) over(partition by memberid) as meat_sum,sum(vegetables) over(partition by memberid) as veg_sum
from source_table t
) t
where meat_sum>0 and veg_sum>0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use CTE:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT      MemberID                        ,
                SUM(Meat)       AS  Meat        ,
                SUM(Vegetables) AS  Vegetables
    FROM        Table
    GROUP BY    MemberID
)
SELECT          Table.*
FROM            Table
INNER JOIN      CTE ON CTE.MemberID =   Table.MemberID
WHERE           CTE.Meat > 0 AND CTE.Vegetables > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest method I can think of:

```
   create table #test (MemberID int, StoreID int, Meat int, Vegetables int)

   insert into #test values (1, 11, 1, 2)
   insert into #test values (1, 12, 0, 1)
   insert into #test values (1, 14, 1, 2)
   insert into #test values (2, 12, 1, 0)
   insert into #test values (3, 12, 1, 0)
   insert into #test values (3, 12, 1, 0)
   insert into #test values (4, 11, 2, 1)
   insert into #test values (4, 13, 0, 1)
   insert into #test values (4, 14, 0, 1)

   Select  * 
   from #test 
   where MemberID in (Select MemberId
       from #test
       group by MemberId, storeID
       having sum(Meat)>0 and sum(vegetables)>0)
```